# Using liquid in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, templates, liquid

Im making a Rails blog engine for learning purpose. I want to use liquid as template engine. I have something like this

```
    ## posts_controller.rb
    ...
    def index
      @posts = Post.all
    end
   ... 
    ## posts/index.html.liquid
    {% for post in posts do %}
      {{ post.title }}
    {% endfor %}
```

That gave me the following error:

```
undefined local variable or method `template' for
#<PostsController:0x103d16290>
```

I already had LiquidView loaded in initializers/liquid.rb
Please let me know what is my problem.
Thank you

Comment: Are you calling `template` somewhere in PostsController? What's your initializer look like? More details = better answers.

Comment: I have no template method in PostsController. Here is my initializer: require 'extras/liquid_view'
ActionView::Template.register_template_handler :liquid, LiquidView
. Just thought liquid would work magically like haml did.

Comment: ok I went through liquid documentation and it really didn't help much. Anyone with the knowledge of setting up a rails app loading liquid local files or knows an open source project doing that please help me out. Thanks much.

Comment: check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7855837/how-to-make-liquid-file-work-in-rails-3  that should fix it.

Answer (score 5):

As I know you should have liquid methods for attributes (in your case for 'title'). try something like this

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  liquid_methods :title
end
```

and see.

If not try to make Post class inherited by Liquid::Drop

like

```
class Posts < Liquid::Drop

end
```

** BTW since you get an error claiming missing template variable make sure your liquid rendering part is as follows

(directly copied from liquid doc)

```
@template = Liquid::Template.parse("hi {{name}}")  # Parses and compiles the template
@template.render( 'name' => 'tobi' )               # Renders the output => "hi tobi"
```

hope this helps

cheers

sameera